# Nfs4_setfacl reports error on files of mounted folder

Tags: acl, nfsv4, setfacl

I mounted an nfsv4 folder (both client and server are CentOS 7.4)
via command

```
$ sudo mount -t nfs -o v4.0,sec=krb5 ark-centos7-ker.qa.arkivio.com:/export/nfs1 /nfs4-mnt-dir
```

created a file via: `touch 11`, then set file's ACL get failed with command

```
$ sudo nfs4_setfacl -a A::auto-stor@qa.arkivio.com:rxtncy /nfs4-mnt-dir/11
[sudo] password for auto-stor@qa.arkivio.com:
Failed setxattr operation: Invalid argument
```

it seems complaining the parameter auto-stor@qa.arkivio.com is invalid,
but this user is already recognized by both nfs4 client and server.

```
$ getent passwd auto-stor@qa.arkivio.com
auto-stor@qa.arkivio.com:*:1712401226:1712400513:auto-stor:/home/auto-stor@qa.arkivio.com:/bin/bash
$ id auto-stor@qa.arkivio.com
uid=1712401226(auto-stor@qa.arkivio.com) gid=1712400513(domain users@qa.arkivio.com) groups=1712400513(domain users@qa.a rkivio.com),10(wheel),1712439592(autostoradmins@qa.arkivio.com),1712439438(certsvc_dcom_access@qa.arkivio.com),171243989 6(passwordpropdeny@qa.arkivio.com),1712400512(domain admins@qa.arkivio.com),1712439802(ats_steph_testgroup@qa.arkivio.co m)
```

What is missing in my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you found your answer or not but i found nfsv4 works best using gid and uid.

Do i would this for a user

```
       sudo nfs4_setfacl -a A:d:180001:RWX /path/to/file
```

For a group it is

```
        sudo nfs4_setfacl -a A:g:29111:RWX /path/to/file
```

Easiest way to get the uid and gid is

```
        id -u username
        getent group groupname
```

Just replace the junk UID and GID i put in the commands with a real one on your system and it will work.